# How to execute bash script from any location?

Tags: unix

In UNIX, I read that moving a shell script to /usr/local/bin will allow you to execute the script from any location by simply typing "[scriptname].sh" and pressing enter.

I have moved a script with both normal user and root permissions but I can't run it.

The script:

```
#! bin/bash

echo "The current date and time is:"
date

echo "The total system uptime is"
uptime

echo "The users currently logged in are:"
who

echo "The current user is:"
who -m

exit 0
```

This is what happens when I try to move and then run the script:

```
[myusername@VDDK13C-6DDE885 ~]$ sudo mv sysinfo.sh /usr/local/bin

[myusername@VDDK13C-6DDE885 ~]$ sysinfo.sh

bash: sysinfo.sh: command not found
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to run the script from *everywhere* you need to add it to your `PATH`. Usually `/usr/local/bin` is in the path of every user so this way it should work.
So check if in your system `/usr/local/bin` is in your `PATH` doing, on your terminal:

```
echo $PATH
```

You should see a lot of paths listed (like `/bin`, `/sbin` etc...). If its not listed you can add it. A even better solution is to keep all your scripts inside a directory, for example in your `home` and add it to your path.

To add a directory in your path you can modify your `shell` init scripts and add the new directories, for example if you're usin the `BASH` shell you can edi your `.bashrc` and add the line:

```
PATH=$PATH:/the_directory_you_want_to_add/:/another_directory/
```

This will append the *new directories*  to your existing `PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to move it somewhere in your path. Try this:

```
echo $PATH
```

I bet /usr/local/bin is not listed.

I handle this by making a bin directory in my $HOME (i.e. `mkdir ~/bin`) and adding this to my ~/.bashrc file (make the file if you don't already have one):

```
export PATH=~/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

This may seem silly to mention, but did you make sure it is executable? Did you chmod +x script.sh? Does the shell script have the correct path to it's shell at the top (i.e #!/bin/bash)? Also, are you using UNIX or LINUX or FreeBSD? (last question is important)

Answer (score -1):

To run executable from any directory:

1)Make a bin directory under your home directory and mv your executable scripts into it.

```
[root@ip9-114-192-179 ~]# cd /home
[root@ip9-114-192-179 home]# mkdir bin
[root@ip9-114-192-179 home]#ls
bin  cloud-init-0.7.4-10.el7.noarch.rpm  cloud-user  epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
```

2)Move your executable scripts in bin direcoty.

```
mv preeti.sh /home/bin
```

3)Now add it to your path variable.And source it.

```
[root@ip9-114-192-179 ~]# echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/home/bin"' >> /etc/profile
[root@ip9-114-192-179 ~]# source /etc/profile
[root@ip9-114-192-179 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/home/bin
```

4)Check if that path is added in path variable.

```
[root@ip9-114-192-179 ~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/home/bin
```

5)Verify if script is running from any random directory.