# Bash script automation

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to create a bash script which does the following:

Creates a file in a folder location

It has to be a new folder

add text data in the file

find and replace the sentence in the file

Change permissions to be read only to everyone apart from the owner it has to be read write and exc

move file to another folder location

Change ownership on file to be root:root

For each step the script needs to display the action in cmd

Please see my attempt below:

```
#!/bin/sh    

#Creates a file in a folder location
#It has to be a new folder
mkdir Alitest /var

#add text data in the file
vim /var/Alitest/action.txt echo "This is a test that I have created. This is to 
see if the output is successful I normally do this manually but a script is required"

#find and replace the sentence in the file 
replace "This is a test that I have created" "The test has been successful" -- action.txt

#Change permissions to be read only to everyone apart from the owner it has to be read write and exc
chmod 004 -- action.txt

chmod 700 -- action.txt

#move file to another folder location
mv /var/Alitest/action.text /var/log

#Change ownership on file to be root:root
chown root:root
```

These are all on separate lines.

Please can some advise on this and how to get the script to show the progress of each task?

Kind Regards
Ali

Comment: "Change permissions to be read only to everyone apart from the owner it has to be read write and exc" - the permissions for this is 744

Comment: "Change ownership on file to be root:root" - to do this you need to run this script as root. Are sure it's a good idea?

Comment: Adding "set -x" to your script will enable debug more and you will see each command displayed before being executed

Comment: Hi Guys, cheers for this I need to set the ownership as root:root as per the request. Does everything else in the the syntax look ok? @user4035 @ramansailopal?

Comment: @AliG Gave you an answer. Tested everything except permissions and moving to /var/log. Let me know, if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh -x

#Create a directory "Alitest" is /var if it doesn't exist
mkdir -p /var/Alitest

#add text data in the file
echo "This is a test that I have created. This is to \
see if the output is successful I normally do this manually but a script is required" > /var/Alitest/action.txt

#find and replace the sentence in the file
sed -i 's/This is a test that I have created/The test has been successful/g' \
    /var/Alitest/action.txt

#Change ownership and permissions on file
chown root:root /var/Alitest/action.txt
chmod 744 /var/Alitest/action.txt

#move file to another folder location
mv /var/Alitest/action.txt /var/log/action.txt
```

Comment: This was perfect and it was a good learning curve :) Is there a way to add a progress bar to my script so that the progress for each step is shown?

Comment: @AliG There are examples of progress bar implementation on stack (try to search). But this script is so trivial, I think the progress bar will be full in an instant.

Comment: Hi Guys, The script did perform as per design on my server however I am on another server the following error output I am unable to run the script from any location and the 744 permissions do not auto apply. Any advice?

Comment: I have had a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650070/how-to-execute-bash-script-from-any-location however is there a way to action this by adding code to the script instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can use 'set -v' or sh script |tee log